# Flask how to apply the first paragraph of a post different class attribute

Tags: jquery, python, css, flask, jinja2

In a small blog application I pull the data from the database and show each post similiar to this:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <h1>Single post </h1>
    {{ post[0]['content'] | markdown}}
</div> -->

{% endblock %}
```

Posts are in markdown format. Is it possible to change the class name of the first paragraph like this: [I suppose may be it should be done with Jquery more easy]

```
<!-- Post Content -->
<p class="lead">This is first paragraph</p>
<p>Another paragraph</p>
.
.
.
```

**Update :** Problem is solved. It seems that I made a typo using this method.

https://jsfiddle.net/qd0pb41v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with pure CSS using [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) pseudo selectors. The index of `nth-child()` is 1-based.

```css
p:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
```

A shortcut to this is the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) pseudo-selector.

```css
p:first-child {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
<p>third</p>
```